# For $h>0$ and a list of positive real numbers, repeatedly halving the current largest number eventually makes every number in the list less than $h$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm writing a proof for a broader problem (which I have to prove using my own method so I won't post it), but the only step I'm not sure how to formally show is this:

> For any $h > 0$, if you take a list of $n$ positive real numbers, and repeatedly divide the current largest number in the list by $2$, the entire list will eventually be less than $h$.

It sounds like common sense to me, but I'm not sure how I would formally/rigorously show that this is the case. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you handle the case when in the list there are identical numbers? Do you divide them all, or only one of them?

Comment: Well it wouldn't matter which, the result is the same. If you divide all of them then you process all of the copies of that number at once, and if you only divide one, you would process all of the copies of that largest number, one right after another.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was something like:
Given $h>0$  , suppose $A_1=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ is a list of n positive real numbers, such that $a_i>a_j \iff i>j\;\;\forall i,j \in \mathbb{N}\cap[1,n]$.
Now divide the greatest element of $A_1$ by 2 and call this new set where $a_n$ is replaced by $\frac{a_n}{2}$, $A_2$ and of course reorder the elements so that we can repeat the process. The key is that: $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{a}{2^x}=0 \; \forall a\in \mathbb{R} $$
Thanks to this, we are sure that there exists a number  $ k_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and in particular a $k \, \in\mathbb{N}$ of the form $\lceil k_0\rceil$ such that after $k$ iterations of this process applied over an element of the set, that element gets smaller than $h$. Then, we have to find this number $k$ for every single element of the set. Let those numbers be a set of the form $K=(k_1, k_2,..., k_n)$ and $$K^´=\sum_{i=1}^n k_i$$
Finally, the set $A_{K^´}$ will have all elements being smaller than $h$

You may need to do some changes depending on additional information or as the user Raskolnikov commented if you are allowing identical numbers on the same list.